# Cyclist to list of functions, and combine their results until a match is found

Tags: python

I have multiple lists of functions, that are called using lambdas:

```
a = [ lambda: func_a1(a11, a12, a13), lambda: func_a2(a21, a23) ...]

b = [ lambda: func_b1(b11, b12), lambda: func_b2(b21) ...]
```

A function can return a result or triggers an exception:

```
def func_a1(a11, a12, a13):
  ...do something
   return result 
  raise CustomException
```

Later in code I'm cycling thru the function. If the function triggers an error, I skip and continue to next function, if not I return. If no return an exception is raised

```
def cycle1():
for f in a :
  try:
    return f()
  except CustomException:
   continue
raise CustomException
```

Similar `def cycle2` for `b` list etc.

Then the results from `cycle1` and `cycle2` are combined and compare with a source of truth.
For simplification, something like:

```
  a,b = cycle1(), cycle2()
  if a + b == c:
    do something
```

The solution has flaws, because if didn't match doesn't return to try other combinations. If `a` and `b` not equal with `c` I want to get the next value, but I'm already out of function. For example:

- if `a[0]` and `b[0]` returns but not equal `c`, then test `a[1][b0]`
- if `a[0]` trigger exception combine `a[1]` with `b[0]`. If not equal `c`, combine `a[1]` and `b[1]`

There are the combinations of the functions returns(that didn't triggered an error).Also I want to favour `a`  cycling first before `b`(a loops, b states on first element, and the loop move b to second elements).

Even scale to have more lists, like `a`, `b`, `c` as list. I'm thinking maybe to use generators to cycle.

I need an ideea, python or pseudo code, to implement it, to avoid the issues of my initial solution

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: My solution has flaws because it stops if function returns and if didn't match later will not try other combinations . I need an idea, code (python pseudo) to avoid the flaws and scale

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do and what you expect to happen. If you use `return` in a loop, you will end the loop. If you don't want that, don't use `return` inside the loop.

Comment: the loops are in functions, and I want to stop all loops when I found a result. I can have loop in loop but doesn't scale plus the loops are not separated as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you want to try out all combination of your functions, if so, that can be done with [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), for example

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([1,2,3],"a b c".split()))
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
>>>
```

For your particular use, you can do the following, but with some changes to your cycle functions that I will show later

```
for a, b in itertools.product(cycle1(), cycle2()):
    if a+b==c:
        #do something
```

the change necessary to work like this, is to transform it into a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators), with is a simple change of return to yield

```
def cycle1():
    for f in a :
        try:
            yield f()
        except CustomException:
            continue
    #raise CustomException
```

as a generator it will *cycle* through all the function on your list `a`, and not just stop on the first success as with is the case for `return`; tho maybe leave out the last exception, if you get to the end of the product combination you will know that you didn't find what you where searching for

here is sample generator

```
>>> def gen(nums):
        for n in nums:
            yield 10+n

    
>>> list(gen([1,2,3]))
[11, 12, 13]
>>>
```

Another change that can be made is, if cycle2 is identical to cycle1 except for the list, then don't repeat yourself and make cycle take that list as argument, and the exception too now that we are at it

```
def cycle(fun_list,exc=CustomException):
    for f in fun_list :
        try:
            yield f()
        except exc:
            continue
```

with that the previous is now

```
for a, b in itertools.product(cycle(list_a), cycle(list_b)):
    if a+b==c:
        #do something
```

Comment: yes I want to do all combinations, but stop when I found a match, and cycle first in a than b, c etc. And a and b are containing functions that need to execute not just strings. I gave example a+b for simplification.